# How should incorrectly encoded URLs be handled?

Tags: apache, url, 404, query-string, url-encoding

Just recently noticed that some sites link with the URL incorrectly percent-encoded, to which my server (LAMP) responds with a 404 Not Found.

For example, for a URL of mine like this:

```
http://www.site.com/page.php?param=value
```

They link to it like this:

```
http://www.site.com/page.php%3Fparam%3Dvalue
```

So:

- Who is wrong? My server for not understanding? or the linking site for not specifying the URL properly?
- Could something be done to configure Apache to understand the misencoded query string delimiter (`%3F` instead of `?`)?
- If not, would it be safe to setup redirects by translating the `%3F` to `?`?

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229371/mod-rewrite-rewriterule-to-handle-html-entities covers your first and third questions. Not sure about the second one.

Comment: Thanks! It covers mostly the third - I'd have to adapt it something more generic but OK. Still, I'd like to know if the referring site is in error or me?

Comment: @Itai It's referring site, since URLs was not generated properly in first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, as @LazyOne said, the third-party URLs are not being properly generated, so the expectation is server to fail - as it is failing right now as you described.

Note that valid HTML and valid URLs are a different thing. You should [escape entities for HTML content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html), but this is not true when [writing links, image addresses, and calls for external files](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt).

Before deciding to escape or not, ask yourself: is this going to be read by a user or by a browser? The answer will tell you which type of encoding you should use.

Comment: That last paragraph is incorrect. Which encoding you use is based on whether you're encoding for an XML/HTML document or a URI/URL. In some cases, you're doing one within the other. For example, ampersands have a special meaning in HTML and XML documents: they're used for character references (e.g. numeric character references such as `&#38;` and `&#x26;` or character entity references such as `&amp;`). But, aside from the document body, ampersands may also show up in meta data and link URLs. In the latter case, you would need to use both encodings, e.g. `/foo?bar=1&amp;baz=hello%20world`.

Comment: The problem with the URL in the question is that the URL encoding is done incorrectly. The reason `?` and `&` in URLs need to be percent encoded is because they have special meanings when defining a query string. So other uses of these characters need to be percent encoded. But in this case, the question mark is _supposed_ to indicate the start of the query string, so it should not have been percent encoded.